# How to identify when a Qt application/widget is dragged across monitors

Tags: windows, qt

My Qt based application has a QMainWindow and another modal widget. This modal widget does not have a restore option. The user is allowed to drag this widget across displays when more than one monitor is available. However, when my widget is large, and the user drags it across to an extended monitor( usually a projector with a very low resolution) the widget is too large for the screen and gets cut.

I want to be able to detect when the user has moved to different screen so that I can resize the widget( and the content within) to fit the new screen's dimension and resolution. Is there any signal that Qt emits for this purpose?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is probably the function call you are looking for:

http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qdesktopwidget.html#screenNumber

```
int QDesktopWidget::screenNumber(const QWidget * widget = 0) const
```

> Returns the index of the screen that contains the largest part of
>   widget, or -1 if the widget not on a screen.

To use this as part of a signal, you should subclass `moveEvent` and `resizeEvent` of a `QWidget` and put your logic for deciding how to place/resize your widget there.  If you want to resize like a browser tab that gets dragged onto a new monitor, you may want to just use the point of the mouse instead of the widget to decide which monitor to react to.

So your end code could look something like this:

```
void Widget::moveEvent(QMoveEvent * e)
{
    m_newScreenSize = qApp->desktop()->screenGeometry(this);
}

void Widget::mouseReleaseEvent(QMouseEvent * e)
{
    this->resize(m_newScreenSize);
}
```

### Other Links and References

QMoveEvent

QResizeEvent

QDesktopWidget

http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qdesktopwidget.html#details

http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qapplication.html#desktop

http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qmoveevent.html#details

http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qwidget.html#moveEvent

http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qwidget.html#resizeEvent

http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qrect.html#intersects
http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qdesktopwidget.html#availableGeometry-2

```
const QRect QDesktopWidget::availableGeometry(const QWidget * widget) const
```